# SUM(x) OVER (PARTITION BY MOD(x, 3)) --need clarification

Tags: google-bigquery

In the following query,1) how the values in the sum column are calculated(6,6,10,10,10,9,9,9)?  2) why MOD(x,3) is used, why not MOD(x,2) or MOD(x,4)? need clarification

```
SELECT
  x,
  SUM(x) OVER (PARTITION BY MOD(x, 3)) AS sum
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) AS x;
```

The above query is in this page, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question  - just run below which has just one additional field

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  x,
  MOD(x, 3) AS x_mod,
  SUM(x) OVER (PARTITION BY MOD(x, 3)) AS SUM
FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]) AS x
```

result is

```sql
Row x   x_mod   sum  
1   3   0       6    
2   3   0       6    
3   1   1       10   
4   4   1       10   
5   4   1       10   
6   1   1       10   
7   2   2       9    
8   5   2       9    
9   2   2       9
```

as you can see now - all values that have same x_mod are summed and that hopefully explains why you see those 6,6,10,10,10,9,9,9

As of your second question  - this is just an example  - no particular reason behind using MOD(x,3) - you can play with MOD(x,2) or MOD(x,4) and explore the behavior - just for you to learn